# JSON exception : unterminated object at character 32

Tags: android, json

```
02-10 09:57:18.850: W/System.err(15122): org.json.JSONException: Unterminated object at character 32 of [{"EVENT_NAME":"BHBH","TIME":11:00:00,"TO_DATE":2015-02-12,"EVENT_DESCRIPTION":"HBHJIK","EVENT_ID":1,"USERNAME":"admin","IMAGE":com.mysql.jdbc.Blob@1a66cb6,"GEOCODE":"bvbv","FROM_DATE":2015-02-09,"EVENT_PLACE":"BJIHNIJ"},{"EVENT_NAME":"marriage","TIME":12:00:00,"TO_DATE":2015-02-13,"EVENT_DESCRIPTION":"hjkhjkhjkh","EVENT_ID":2,"USERNAME":"admin","IMAGE":com.mysql.jdbc.Blob@12b2fef,"GEOCODE":"yuytre","FROM_DATE":2015-02-09,"EVENT_PLACE":"gmnfdgvmn"}]
02-10 09:57:18.850: W/System.err(15122):    at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:450)
02-10 09:57:18.850: W/System.err(15122):    at org.json.JSONTokener.readObject(JSONTokener.java:394)
02-10 09:57:18.860: W/System.err(15122):    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:100)
02-10 09:57:18.860: W/System.err(15122):    at org.json.JSONTokener.readArray(JSONTokener.java:430)
02-10 09:57:18.860: W/System.err(15122):    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:103)
02-10 09:57:18.860: W/System.err(15122):    at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:87)
02-10 09:57:18.860: W/System.err(15122):    at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:103)
02-10 09:57:18.860: W/System.err(15122):    at com.eventscorner.activity.HomeActivity$EventsAsyncTask.forList(HomeActivity.java:101)
02-10 09:57:18.860: W/System.err(15122):    at com.eventscorner.activity.HomeActivity$EventsAsyncTask.onPostExecute(HomeActivity.java:83)
02-10 09:57:18.860: W/System.err(15122):    at com.eventscorner.activity.HomeActivity$EventsAsyncTask.onPostExecute(HomeActivity.java:1)
02-10 09:57:18.860: W/System.err(15122):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
02-10 09:57:18.860: W/System.err(15122):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
02-10 09:57:18.870: W/System.err(15122):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
02-10 09:57:18.870: W/System.err(15122):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-10 09:57:18.870: W/System.err(15122):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-10 09:57:18.870: W/System.err(15122):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5214)
02-10 09:57:18.870: W/System.err(15122):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-10 09:57:18.870: W/System.err(15122):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-10 09:57:18.870: W/System.err(15122):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
02-10 09:57:18.870: W/System.err(15122):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
02-10 09:57:18.870: W/System.err(15122):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: what is the json you are getting

Answer (score 0):

```
"TIME":11:00:00,"TO_DATE":2015-02-12
```

The values `11:00:00` and `2015-02-12` must be quoted.

Indeed, you need to quote anything other than numbers, `true`, `false` or`null` into strings. You can refer to JSON grammar in http://json.org/ .

Answer (score 0):

this web site is very good for finding json validation errors

http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

paste your json into it and press PROCESS